# Force caching data on Client Side

Tags: php, javascript

I am writing a script that will load custom javascript and images based on details entered by user (using php on server). Is there a way to force these JS and images to be cached on browser on client side to reduce load on server when similar data is requested next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a way you can set expire headers to a longer period. i.e. if you are using .htaccess write this in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType image/x-icon .ico

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/* A86400
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000

ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ".*/(uploads|weather)/.*\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$" is_monthly=true
Header set cache-control: max-age=604800 env=is_monthly
```

Comment: Are you sure this thing will affect caching on client side (browser)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look at your servers caching defaults, and see how they can be controlled, if its apache there is mod_cache and mod_expire which you can use via .htaccess:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Or.. you could serve the files up as PHP and use headers for cache-control.  But that would be crazy...

Comment: That sounds like caching on server side, correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Na, expires controls what headers go out on the HTTP response, then the client does what it should.

Comment: great thanx, let me try that!